# Bad type inference for the Vec of dynamic closures

Tags: rust, closures, type-inference

I am trying to get a list of partially applied functions, like so:

```
fn partially_applied() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];

    xs.into_iter().map(|x| Box::new(move |y| x + y)).collect() 
}
```

The compiler yields an error to me:

error[E0277]: a value of type std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<dyn std::ops::Fn(u32) -> u32>> cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type std::boxed::Box<[closure@src/main.rs:4:41: 4:57]>

---

The subsequent attempts also did not work:

1.

```
fn partially_applied_with_explicit_collect_type() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];

    xs.into_iter().map(|x| Box::new(move |y| x + y)).collect::<Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>>>() 
}
```

2. 

```
fn partially_applied_with_explicit_vec_type() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];

    let mut res: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> = xs.into_iter().map(|x| Box::new(move |y| x + y)).collect(); 
    res 
}
```

3. 

```
fn partially_applied_with_explicit_push() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];

    let mut res = vec![];

    for x in xs { 
        res.push(Box::new(move |y| x + y)); 
    }

    res 
}
```

And only this attempt was finally succeeded!

```
fn partially_applied_with_explicit_push_and_vec_type() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];

    let mut res: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> = vec![];

    for x in xs { 
        res.push(Box::new(move |y| x + y)); 
    }

    res 
}
```

---

Why the type inference is so bad when it comes to dynamic closures?

Why the `collect` did not work in the first attempts?

Is there a better way to utilize a type inference to express such an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is that every closure gets its own unnamable type of which it is the sole member. Furthermore, while it the compiler can automatically cast a particular boxed closure into `Box<dyn *closure's type*>`, it cannot reach down deeper into generic types to perform the upcasting.

So the following is ok:

```rust
fn closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32> {
    Box::new(|x| x)
}
```

But this is not:

```rust
fn partially_applied() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];
    xs.into_iter().map(|x| Box::new(move |y| x + y)).collect() 
}
```

Why not?

```
value of type `Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>>` cannot be built from
`std::iter::Iterator<Item=Box<[closure@src/main.rs:12:37: 12:51]>>`

help: the trait `FromIterator<Box<[closure@src/main.rs:12:37: 12:51]>>`
is not implemented for `Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>>`
```

It's because the trait bound in `FromIterator` for `Vec` is

```rust
impl<T> FromIterator<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(iter: I) -> Vec<T> { ... }
}
```

and `Box<[closure@src/main.rs]>` is a distinct type from `Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>`.

So the question is not "why is Rust's type inference failing here" but rather "why does Vec not implement the following":

```rust
impl<T, U> FromIterator<T> for Vec<U>
where T: Into<U> {
    fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(iter: I) -> Vec<U> { ... }
}
```

That, I don't know. I suspect this would lead to its own problems with type inference when there are multiple pairs of `T,U` that would make things work.

N.B. you can cast your boxes to the correct type as follows:

```rust
fn partially_applied() -> Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>> {
    let xs = vec![1_u32, 2, 3];

    xs.into_iter()
        .map(|x| Box::new(move |y| x + y) as Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>)
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: Besides problems with inference, this also goes against Rust's philosophy "explicit is better than implicit". It would be very bad if, for example, `Vec::<String>::from_iterator(vec!["a", "b", "c"])` would allocate behind your back to convert the `&str`s to `String`s. Also, this would not solve this specific problem since `Box<dyn Fn>: !From<Box<[closure]>>`.